# Cannot post reseed for secured layers

Tags: geowebcache, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to reseed some layers via rest service. The call seems to work and it return OK but nothing happens. When I look into DEBUG logs on the server is see this

---

2016-06-23 09:08:57,849 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/gwc/rest/seed/sigmap_private:seismic_new_to_db_view'; to: '/gwc/rest/seed/sigmap_private:seismic_new_to_db_view'  and httpMethod= POST
2016-06-23 09:08:57,850 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
2016-06-23 09:08:57,850 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/gwc/rest/seed/sigmap_private:seismic_new_to_db_view'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=false
2016-06-23 09:08:57,850 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [POST, DELETE, PUT]
2016-06-23 09:08:57,850 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/gwc/rest/seed/sigmap_private:seismic_new_to_db_view'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
2016-06-23 09:08:57,850 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
2016-06-23 09:08:57,850 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/gwc/rest/seed/sigmap_private:seismic_new_to_db_view]
2016-06-23 09:08:57,852 DEBUG [org.geoserver.gwc.layer] - --> GWC Seeder Thread-3 submitting getMap request for meta grid location [0, 0, 0] on org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerMetaTile@3eaad821
2016-06-23 09:08:57,853 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-06-23 09:08:57,859 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
2016-06-23 09:08:57,881 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing seismic_new_to_db style for sigmap_private:seismic_new_to_db_view
2016-06-23 09:08:57,883 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms] - setting up map
2016-06-23 09:08:57,883 ERROR [org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder] - Problem communicating with GeoServer
org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheException: Problem communicating with GeoServer
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:523)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:712)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Cannot access PostGISPrivate as anonymous
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.unauthorizedAccess(SecureCatalogImpl.java:895)
    at org.geoserver.security.decorators.SecuredDataStoreInfo.getDataStore(SecuredDataStoreInfo.java:46)
    at org.geoserver.security.decorators.SecuredDataStoreInfo.getDataStore(SecuredDataStoreInfo.java:29)
    at org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo.getFeatureSource(MapLayerInfo.java:317)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:363)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:254)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:125)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:80)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:792)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.dispatchOwsRequest(GWC.java:1174)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:573)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:518)
    ... 9 more

---

The key is probably in this line 
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Cannot access PostGISPrivate as anonymous
I do have this whole workspace secured via Data/Role in geoserver.
It seems to me that geowebcache is not passing authentication headers to the geoserver in this case.
I am using geoserver 2.6.2 with integrated GWC version 1.6.1, build 1.6.x/01bbae5727a8a05babbd06e0dc2d4024e9318362 on Ubuntu

Comment: It looks like tile caching and security don't mix very well.  I am thinking of removing security temporarily so I can  issue the reseed calls and then placing the security back in. In order to do that I have another question; **Can I manage layer security via rest calls?**

Comment: Yes, you can manage security as well explained [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/rest.html)